# How to read the file and remove the field of each line then add the extra row to each line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I do have two shell script , read the file(file1) and remove the first field of the file ( output result redirect to the file2)
, then second script again read above modified file (file2) then add extra field to each line (file3),
How to do this in single script without using two shell script .

```
#!/bin/bash
#  loop on all .txt files
for i in File1.txt; do
#  remove first column
cut -d' ' -f2- < $i > File2.txt
done  

#!/bin/bash
filename='File2.txt'
while read line; do
# reading each line
echo "$RANDOM $line" >> File3.txt
done < $filename


File1.txt
Date Field2 Field3
20111 aaaa  bbbb
33111 bbbb  vvvv
44444 cccc  gggg

File2.txt
Field2 Field3
aaaa  bbbb
bbbb  vvvv
cccc  gggg

File3.txt
New  Field2 Fileld3
1    aaaa  bbbb
2    bbbb  vvvv
1    cccc  gggg
```

Comment: Looks like homework question.

Comment: What is the point of using a `for` loop for a single file (`for i in File1.txt`) ?

Comment: @M.NejatAydin For loop doing remove the first column in File1.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea:

```
new="New"

while read -r ignore rest_of_line
do
    echo "$new $rest_of_line"
    new=$RANDOM
done < file1.txt > file3.txt
```

This generates:

```
$ cat file3.txt
New Field2 Field3
29258 aaaa  bbbb
31885 bbbb  vvvv
15550 cccc  gggg
```

**NOTE:** it's not clear (to me) what the input/output field delimiters are so for now I'm assuming any white space on input and a single space on output; should be (relatively) easy to modify per OP's requirement

Comment: i'm using first for loop for remove the first column in File1.txt  , in this while loop ignore keyword dong same thing ?

Comment: `ignore` is a dummy variable that holds the first space-delimited field from an input line; the last variable - `rest_of_line` - gets populated with ... the rest of the input line; the fact that I don't use `ignore` anywhere in the rest of the script means that I (effectively) 'remove' the first field from the data set; often times you'll see people use something like an underscore, eg, `read -r _ fld2 _ _ fld5 rest_of_line` where the `_` is used here to show that we don't care about values in fields 1,3 and 4; variable names are left up to the devloper to choose